# Why doesn't the voltage source ever supply current in my circuit?

Tags: circuit-protection

I'm trying to make a protection circuit for a battery. The PMOS is intended to prevent reverse current. The diode is intended to prevent the output voltage from exceeding 10V. When I simulate the circuit however, the voltage source doesn't supply any significant current until after the output voltage leaves the intended operating range of ~10 V. What am I missing?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWAooi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is your source voltage really 1V? If not, please correct the schematic.

Comment: How much current do you expect, at what supply voltage.  If the supply voltage is under 10 volts, only R2 will draw current.  At 10 volts, it will only draw 0.2 mA.

Comment: When using a PMOS, the bulk/source connection should be connected to the positive supply voltage, the way you have connected things means that the drain-bulk diode in the PMOS is now in **forward mode**. That means, the PMOS will not do anything useful when connected like this. Even if you swap drain and source to the correct positions, the Vgs = 1 V is not enough to fully switch on the PMOS. You will need like 3 V for that.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie This is a polarity protection circuit with the FET connected with opposite polarity to "usual". When battery polarity is correct the body diode conducts **AND** as Vgate is negative relative to source the FET is enhanced - minimal Vdrop occurs across the FTE. When battery polarity is reverse to desired the body diode blocks AND the FET is not turned on. It works very well as long as Vbat >> Vgsth. At lower voltages the body diode still conducts..

Answer (score 2):

[IRF9530 datasheet here](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf9530npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535611b9931dc1)

Rdson is about 0.2 Ohm.
Not stunningly good but OK at the sort of load resistance (50k) shown.

Rgsth = FET turn on voltage is around 4 to 5 volts typically.
AT battery voltages below about 4V the FET will be off and only the body diode provides a forward current path.

From 4V+ FET will start to conduct
but say 6V + Vbattery is needed tor turn FET on well.

**Correct battery polarity:**

There are 3 modes:

- Vbattery > Vd1. MOSFET body diode conducts, FET is enhanced (turned on), zener clamps Vload at Vzener.
- Vbattery < Vgsth of FET.
  Body diode conducts to supply load
  **but** FET is off
  **and** body diode drop is typically 1V -
  **so** at low Vbat the current may be less than expected.
- Vz > Vbat > (Vgsth + a few volts).
  FET is turned on.
  Iload ~= Vbat/(R1+R2)

If current is less than expected check that there is enough Vbat to turn FET on AND that FET is indeed connected as shown.

**Reverse battery polarity**

Body diode blocks.
FET is turned off.
Iload ~~= 0.
You knew that.